# Mongodb- Query documents between two timestamp

Tags: mongodb

I have documents in the following structure:

```
{
"escalation" : null,
"reclassified" : false,
"timestamp" : "1559164897437",
"endFlow" : "false",
"channel" : "web",
"intents" : null
},
{
"escalation" : null,
"reclassified" : false,
"timestamp" : "1565196671234",
"endFlow" : "true",
"channel" : "web",
"intents" : null
}
```

I would like to query documents like above between two timestamps, say "1559254897437" and "1563996671234".
Please note that I have the value of timestamp field stored as string, not integer.

**What I have tried:**

```
db.getCollection('messagelogs').find({
    'timestamp':{
        $lte:1559164897437,
        $gte:1560351891811}
        })
```

Unfortunately, this is returning any documents.

**What is the correct query to fetch documents between two timestamps?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the timestamp is present as String in DB, we need to query it in the string range and not numeric. The following query can get you the expected output:

```
db.getCollection('messagelogs').find(
{
    'timestamp':{
        $gte:'1559164897437',
        $lte:'1560351891811'
    }
})
```

Output:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d4b1ccdcbfa696dcd9924a3"),
    "escalation" : null,
    "reclassified" : false,
    "timestamp" : "1559164897437",
    "endFlow" : "false",
    "channel" : "web",
    "intents" : null
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Basically what you're trying there is something like AND operation on each document, saying you need a document having timestamp $lte a timestamp & at the same-time  $gte a different timestamp, instead you need to do OR to get outer boundaries i.e; bring documents out if any one condition matches, Please do this :

```
db.getCollection('messagelogs').find({$or: [{'timestamp': {$lte:'1559164897437'}}, {'timestamp': {$gte:'1560351891811'}}] })
```

assuming you did a mistake, if you're in need of docs between particular times, you need to swap your timestamps :

```
db.getCollection('messagelogs').find({$and: [{'timestamp': {$lte:'1560351891811'}}, {'timestamp': {$gte:'1559164897437'}}] })
```

or simply :

```
db.getCollection('messagelogs').find({'timestamp': {$gte:'1559164897437', $lte: '1560351891811'}})
```